# Why does Java ignore the first line of a .properties file?

Tags: java, properties-file

I was working with an app that loads a `.properties` file with `java.util.Properties` like this:

```
Properties _properties = new Properties();
_properties.load(new FileInputStream("app.properties"));
```

The properties file (initially) was this:

```
app=myApp
dbLogin=myDbLogin
version=0.9.8.10
server=1
freq=10000
stateGap=360000
```

The strange thing was that when I called `_properties.getProperty("app")`, it always returned `null`, however I could load all of the other properties without any issues. I solved the problem by adding a comment to the top of the properties file, then everything worked fine.

My question is: Why does Java do this? I can't seem to find any documentation about this, and it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: it doesn't do it, are you sure you are referring to same file ?

Comment: Why is `'app.properties'` in single quotes?

Comment: Post a real example. Your Java code is illegal, my *guess* is you had a space after "app" in your real properties file.

Comment: there's no "getString()" method in Properties

Comment: I'm positive it is finding the right file; because I get an IOException when I delete it and the properties reflect my changes when I save it.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `getString`; I've updated my code.

Comment: If the problem is reproducible, share the code. Otherwise it's guessing.

Comment: Also, @ElliottFrisch the documentation on properties says whitespace between properties and equals signs is ignored, so `app=myApp` is equivalent to `app = myApp`.

Comment: @CullenJ I'd look for invalid characters in your properties file. Check the file using some hex dump utility

Comment: first of all, as others mentioned your code will fail in compilation. You should use double quote and also use `_properties.getProperty("app")`. But mostly I am suspicious about the file you are loading. Are you sure you are pointing at the correct path? try to print absolutePath or canonicalPath of the file and make sure it is the one you want.

Comment: @pmp thanks; I've updated my example. I already addressed how I know that it is actually loading the file. I've printed the working directory to verify this as well.

Comment: And if it were invalid characters, why would it work properly after I add a comment as the first line?

Comment: @CullenJ Can you perhaps create a complete new properties file, and load its first property. You'll understand that there is nothing wrong with Java implementation, but it's something with your properties file that is wrong.

Comment: just give a code sample and the file you use already. It's silly to make us guess.

Comment: BOM at file beginning?

Comment: I gave you my example; are you saying that if you build an app with a properties file exactly like the one in my example, it works fine? Because it doesn't for me, and this is the code I'm using.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov exactly.

Comment: @CullenJ add to your question the hexdump for your properties file pls

Comment: oh right @KonstantinV.Salikhov . It might be BOM.
Create brand new file (do not copy from old one). Write them and make sure you save it with correct encoding

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov and pmp, I think encoding was the problem; the files was UTF-8, so I changed it ANSI and it worked. Thanks for your help on this! If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: But all of the shown characters have the same byte representation in UTF-8 and ASCII (not ANSI) so it can't be that alone.

Comment: And a BOM is only used with UTF-16, never for UTF-8.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html : "The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store properties from and to a character based stream in a simple line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, **except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding**."

Comment: Yeah @laune I'm not sure why this would be an issue, but that's literally all I needed to change to get it to work.

Comment: @laune BOM can happen on any non unicode encoding. And as CullenJ mentioned, he was using wrong encoding.
It could happen if a character inserted into the file is not supported by file encoding - although you delete it, it might still be there-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @KonstantinV.Salikhov and @pms for their help in hunting this down; I decided to post the answer that was discovered to save people hunting through the comments.

The problem was that my file was the wrong encoding, as mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store properties from and to a character based stream in a simple line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, **except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding.**

(Emphasis mine).

I changed the encoding of the properties file to ISO-8859-1 and everything worked.

Comment: You should strive to always use UTF-8 without BOM. You can then use InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter for manipulation. With Reader/Writer you can specify encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not handle the BOM correctly – you can see it in the properties as key. It is possible to save the file UTF-8 but without BOM. In vim for instance

```
:set nobomb
```

[See vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)