# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key

Tags: java, servlets, resourcebundle

I don't know whats going on.
Here is my Titles_en_US.properties file:

```
WEBSITE.TITLE       = Hello World       

FOOTER.DISCLAIMER       = Disclaimer
FOOTER.TERMS_OF_USE     = Terms of Use
FOOTER.PRIVACY_POLICY   = Privacy Policy
```

Here is my method:

```
private String getTitle() throws Exception {    
    System.out.println("\n\n==>"+getProperty("FOOTER.DISCLAIMER",LabelsFile()));
    return getProperty("WEBSITE.TITLE", LabelsFile());
}
```

Both `FOOTER.DISCLAIMER` and `WEBSITE.TITLE` in same properties file but one is working and other is throwing following error:

```
==>Disclaimer
Resources.ResourceBundle.java:getProperty()
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key WEBSITE.TITLE
```

Please advise where I am making mistake?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that when I give line break then its working fine. Not able to understand why resource bundle is not reading from 1st line of property file?

Comment: avoid whitespaces in your keys

Comment: There is no white space in keys but dot

Comment: between key and = sign?

Comment: space between key and = sign doesn't matters

Comment: Good Luck, Ghayel ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when I give a line break at top of my property file then it started work fine. Then I searched why the java ResourceBundle is not reading first line of the property file and found this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810028/why-does-java-ignore-the-first-line-of-a-properties-file). In this post said that:

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store
>   properties from and to a character based stream in a simple
>   line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) /
>   store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the
>   load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output
>   stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding.

and also in the aforementioned post advised to change the encoding of the properties file to ISO-8859-1.