# Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, sc.title

Tags: java

I use Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) and try to develop a pen & paper character creation program as an exercise to learn to work with different files like xml and properties.

My *ResBundle.properties*-file looks like this:

```
cc.male=male
cc.female=female
cc.askForGender=Choose a gender for your hero

sc.btnStart=Start\n Creation
sc.title=Creation of a Setting
sc.creationProps=Creation Properties
sc.creationPropsComment=Properties for character creation
```

It is a lot longer and has 60 lines of code similar to the shown part. My main JFrame uses the file like shown below:

```
JMenuItem mntmNewchar = new JMenuItem(lang.getString("gui.char.new"));
```

My second JFrame, which I use to create a new Character/World has the same code. For example:

```
setTitle(lang.getString("sc.title"));
```

Still I get the Exception:

> Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key sc.title

My main Method:

```
try {
    lang = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResBundle", new Locale("en"));
} catch(MissingResourceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mainFrame = new MainFrame();
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The most answers I find to this question deal with the same Exception. But they only tell me how I have to move the properties file into my source foulder/class path folder. I had the Exception before and moved the file, so now it is in the folder *lib/lang* which I added to my build path as a source folder (with Eclipse). After that I coul'd continue programming until I got the Exception message described above.

When I use just another key for testing, it works. I tried to rename the key in the properties file and in my program, but the Exception still occurs.

The weirdest part is, that it already worked. I could open a second JFrame through a button and the same key!, that means

> "sc.title"

and other keys I use in the second JFrame, didn't throw an Exception. Just after some adaptations of other swing components, I couldn't start my program anymore because of that Exception.

I found this similar question:

[java.util.missingresourceexception: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.ResourceBundle, key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599435/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-resource-for-bundle-java-util-pro)

I inserted a line break as a first line, but that changes nothing. Also I found a question which was asked 6 month ago, but still got no answer. Still it is the same problem as I am having:

[Java - ResourceBundle Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322325/java-resourcebundle-cant-find-resource-for-bundle-java-util-propertyresourceb)

I hope someone can help me or describe, why the JVM cant find the key. I think I have the right structure of the properties-file and I don't know, why it's not working.

Thank you very much for everyone who can help me a little or a lot.

---

Edit (Answer @arthur):

My current folder structure- root folder:

[image: fodler tree]

lib/lang/ResBundle.properties

Eclipse shows me, that I included the folder as follows

- Eclipse properties for my java project. The tab "Java Build Path" ist shown

[image: Eclipse properties for my java project. The tab "Java Build Path" ist shown]

Comment: please show your current folder structure. It can not find it because it is not on the build/class path of your application

Comment: I tried moving the ResBundle.properties file into the normal build/class path of my application, but the Exception still occurs. If I move it in another folder, which is not in the build/class path, I get a slightly different Exception stack trace, so I think, this is not the trigger for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake and I'm deeply sorry that I posted a question which had such a simple solution. I checked the line which uses the resource bundle key and isn't workin a hundred times but just now I noticed, that I got confused with the brackets. It should be

> String str = ResourceBundleVariable.getString("key");

I made the mistake, that I included the string which follows the return of the *getString* method in the bracket of the *getString* method itself. That way it searched for the key: *"key: "* and not for the right one: *"key"*. My **wrong** code:

```
String str = ResourceBundleVariable.getString("key"+": "); //ATTENTION Code not operating as intended
```

The **right** code which is working now as intended:

```
String str = ResourceBundleVariable.getString("key")+": ";
```